# Sum separate columns based upon duplicate conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

How do I create a worksheet formula to to the following:

Look for Policy Number duplicates in column `B`,  then for corresponding Pay Date duplicates in column `C`. If both contain duplicates, sum the Premium row amounts in `D` and then separately sum the Commission row amounts in `E` (e.g. `Jane Doe`).

If a duplicate Policy Number in column `B`, does not have a corresponding duplicate Pay Date in `C`, then do nothing (e.g. `John Smith`).

[image: Image of Excel Data as described]

Comment: (1) I’m sure you understand what you want.  Mind-readers probably can tell what you’re thinking, also.  Most of use aren’t mind-readers.  I don’t understand what you want.  Your sample data sheet is good, but you need to show us the results you want, too. (2) We prefer that you not post text (and numbers) as images.  Post a textual representation of your data, as was done [here](//superuser.com/q/889201/150988) and [here](//superuser.com/q/892744/150988); use the [Format Text as Table](https://senseful.github.io/text-table) … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  or the [Plain Text Tables generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) site if you want.  (3) We prefer not to just give people full solutions.  Please try to solve this yourself and post your attempt, and explain where you got stuck.  … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @Scott 1) Nice table generator site. Doesn't *quite* do everything I want, though. 2) Just a suggestion, maybe your two comments would look better split into four separate comments? (If you want you can fix it this time by re-posting your comments after which I'll clean up mine.)

Comment: @robinCTS: Thanks. (I have no affiliation with either of the table-generating sites.) I prefer to minimize the total number of comments, because the system doesn’t always display all the comments on each post (initially); you have to ask to see them all. It seems like, the more comments get posted, the more probable it is that some of them will be hidden. … … … … … … … … … … P.S. I chose not to edit Julie’s image into her question because I thought it didn’t illuminate the question enough (as I said in my comments). I’m not criticizing you; just offering a point of view for your consideration.

Comment: @Scott 1) Good point about the splitting of the comments. Even though five comments are *always* displayed, the first five will (only) get bumped out by higher upvoted ones (eventually). 2) Also good point about not in-lining the image. Though someone else will just end up doing so anyway ;-) However, it's possible it could make it even *more* obvious that the question is lacking where/what the results should be. I'll keep it in mind from now on, though. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the `SUMIFS` function to sum duplicates like this.

I converted your range to an EXCEL TABLE and with your range column names and then applied these formulas.

**To get Premium Sums**

```
=IF(SUMIFS([Premium],[Policy Number],[@[Policy Number]],[Pay Date],[@[Pay Date]])<>[@Premium], SUMIFS([Premium],[Policy Number],[@[Policy Number]],[Pay Date],[@[Pay Date]]),"")
```

**To get Commissioner Sums**

```
=IF(ISNUMBER([@Payout]), SUMIFS([Commission],[Policy Number],[@[Policy Number]],[Pay Date],[@[Pay Date]]), "")
```

---

The formulas will work as is if your range is an excel table with the same column names.  However, you can keep the range by replacing all the [xxx] with specific ranges.  [Policy Number] is the whole `Policy Number` column where [@[Policy Number]] is the specific cell on the row in the `Policy Number` column where the formula is applied.